# Using willDeleteItemsAt and didSelectItemAt in MaterialComponents

Tags: ios, material-components

There is problem with using MaterialComponents.MaterialCollections. 
I am using two functions:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

and

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDeleteItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

When i select cell it will go to another ViewController, it's okey. But when i enable editing mode and cells start to float, i want just to pick cells for delete. But first i go to another View, than go back, mine cell 
[already tagged for delete.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oziBF.png)
How to interrupt segue to another view and just select?